# Layered navigation on homepage in magento 1.9 Call to a member function load() on a non-object in Error Occured

Tags: cms, layered-navigation, home

I am trying to show a layered navigation on homepage. I m using magento 1.9.0. and inserted following xml in `Layout Update XML`

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Then in `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\layer.php` modified function `getCurrentCategory()` as follows to get root category on home-page:

```
public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    $category = $this->getData(’current_category’);
    if (is_null($category)) {
        if ($category = Mage::registry(’current_category’)) {
            $this->setData(’current_category’, $category);
        }
        else {
            $category = false;
            $this->setData(’current_category’, $category);
        }
    }

    // added to make this work for front page:
    if(is_null($category) || $category == false) {
        $home_category = Mage::getModel(’catalog/category’)->load(4); //number must correspond to ‘all products page’ category
        $this->setData(’current_category’, $home_category);
        $category = $this->getData(’current_category’);

        return $category;

    }

    //end addition

    return $category; 
}
```

But Following error has occurred:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer.php on line 174

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question and it works it like a charm.

just edit in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\layer.php

```
public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    $category = $this->getData('current_category');
    if (is_null($category)) {
        if ($category = Mage::registry('current_category')) {
            $this->setData('current_category', $category);
        }
        else {
        $category = false;
        $this->setData('current_category', $category);
    }
}

// added to make this work for front page:
if(is_null($category) || $category == false) {
    $home_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4); //number must correspond to 'all products page' category
    $this->setData('current_category', $home_category);
    $category = $this->getData('current_category');

    return $category;

}

//end addition

return $category; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try check you single quote
You should use ' instead ’

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this related to your or not,I understood this way that's why i am posting

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(enter you category id);
```

like

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(43);
```

I think this is help full for you

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `category id`  to layer for getting layer navigation

```
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>yourcatId</category_id></action>
```

Code should like this:

```
 <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
 <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>yourcatId</category_id></action>
 </block>
```